# Ember: What exactly the chain of modelFor and get do at Route?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am in Route.
What exactly the chain of **modelFor** and **get** do the job ?

Syntax:

```
import Ember from "ember";

var PagesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return this.modelFor('campaign').get('pages'); # what exactly it is doing here ?
    }
});
export default PagesRoute;
```

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_modelFor) before asking?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question shows no research effort.

Comment: Shows no research effort ? who said to you ? am i said ? you should ask me, elaborate the question in more detail..I know why we use modelFor. My question is here how chain system works

Comment: Check what `modelFor` returns.

Comment: ModelFor returns the parent route

Comment: simple story: campaign is model with pages attribute(hasMany relationship).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88162/discussion-between-kitler-and-user2224250).

Answer (score 1):

It is to get `model` of `campaign` route from other route, to have access to it. Then `.get()` is used to get `model.pages` property of `campaign` route `model`.